# audio onError arguments

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a small HTML5-based website. At some point I want to play a sound. I'm playing the sound like this:

```
    sound = new Audio(url);
    sound.addEventListener("error", function(e) { 
               console.log("Logging playback error: " + e); });
    sound.load();
    sound.play();
```

When an error occurs, I can't figure out what's in `e`. Unfortunately the error occurs only on an iPad, so I can't use `Firebug` to debug it. Nowhere in the documentation did I found the description of the argument.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did the same search. e isn't documented *anywhere*. It might be e.text, but it also might be e.message. I wonder what else `e` contains.

Comment: Ok, could you try to add some listing like in this example only for the 'error' listener? http://jsfiddle.net/BvDVG/2

Comment: As you can see, the error handler just tries to log the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I probably found that [error](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_error.asp) message object. The error code is in `sound.error.code` or also `e.currentTarget.error.code` property and it can contain one of the following 4 digits:

```
MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED=1
MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK=2
MEDIA_ERR_DECODE=3
MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED=4
```

[examined it @jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BvDVG/10/)

Comment: jsfiddle is excellent! Thanks. However, is there *any* documentation of this? I really don't want to jsfiddle on various browsers just to make sure things are as I expect them to be. How come this isn't documented anywhere?

Comment: I dunno, probably not many people use it. And also it seems to be a new property. Googled second time and found that MediaError object e.g. here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_av_dom.asp

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [@Stano answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11725663/11559570) I've created a function that will output the error message instead of the code number. It uses [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method from ES6, but it has full support in all major browsers at the time of writing (11/2019).

```
const getMediaErrorMessage = error => Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(error.currentTarget.error)).find(key => error.currentTarget.error[key] === error.currentTarget.error.code);
```

This is a snippet presenting the usage of the function:

```js
const getMediaErrorMessage = error => Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(error.currentTarget.error)).find(key => error.currentTarget.error[key] === error.currentTarget.error.code);

const url = 'xxx';  // using wrong url, to get an error
const sound = new Audio(url);
sound.addEventListener('error', e => console.log(`Media error occurred: ${getMediaErrorMessage(e)}`));
sound.load();
sound.play();
```